# How did Epic Games achieve this 3D effect on their Fortnite site?

Tags: web, 3d, three.js, epic

I have been looking at Epic Games' [Fortnites Website](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/home) and I am trying to figure out how they achieved the 3D effect on the page:

[Epic Games' Fortnite website - scrolled down to 3rd slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCjAb.jpg)

Does any one have any idea how to do it? I would really like something similar to a project I'm working on. I have found Three.js, but I am quite sure that is not the solution they went with.

Comment: Looks like a pre-rendered background to me, try blender, but then maybe it's because I'm on my phone

Comment: Based on the code, they're using the Unreal engine. I don't have any experience with this engine, so changing your tags to address the appropriate topic might help get a better answer to your question. For now, [here's where you can find more information](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/HTML5/).

Comment: It's mostly parallax effect, no real 3D going on here. I found this library years ago that was really helpful in making nifty parallax effects, it might help you too: http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

Answer (score 4):

For these types of questions, i can only recommend to install [spector.js](http://spector.babylonjs.com/) and have a look yourself. In short: everything you see is 100% faked.

I mean, that's always the case. In fact, if you want to build something like that, your first question should always be: how much of this can I fake and still get away with that?

In this example, it turns out: everything. Just open the devtools and click through all the assets in the network-tab. You will find these two textures:

[image: texture]
[image: normalmap]

looks familiar, right?

So what they appear to be doing is they are using three.js with some custom shaders to handle the translations, the flickering of the lights and the highlighting. These effects are computed using the normal-map and an additional mask-texture which I couldn't quite figure out what it does. But again, if you look at the scene in spector.js you can see the shaders used for every drawcall.

The only thing that is a bit more complex is the little robot-friend in the bottom left corner. But again, it's not 3d as in meshes and so on but rather a set of flat textured quads running a bones-animation thing.

I think that makes it a really great website after all.

Given that epic is building the unreal-engine I would suspect the original renders were done there. And I agree, the lighting looks really amazing :)

Comment: wow, that spector.js extension is awesome, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple parallax effect using animated sprite sheets.

Parallax effect is achieved by using several layers of images/video on top of one another in different Z-depth.

You can achieve the moving part by using the [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) event to track the cursor.

Comment: Maxymilian is talking about a "mission" that loads while sitting on the main page. You're right, the main site is just a bunch of layers controlled by CSS, but the in-mission interface does use the Unreal engine.